# sql order by most recent dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table in my database:

```
    INSERT INTO `shop_stats` (`date`, `value`) VALUES
('09/2014', 326),
('08/2014', 1007),
('07/2014', 1108),
('06/2014', 1027),
('05/2014', 895),
('04/2014', 650),
('03/2014', 683),
('02/2014', 563),
('01/2014', 499),
('12/2013', 568),
('11/2013', 522),
('10/2013', 371),
('09/2013', 347),
('08/2013', 376),
('07/2013', 418),
('06/2013', 567),
('05/2013', 357);
```

i need to find a way to display the last 12 months.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_stats ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 12
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which result have you about your query?

Comment: Store dates in a proper date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) like this

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 shop_stats 
order by
 STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%Y') DESC LIMIT 12
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/466c56/5)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM shop_stats WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) LIMIT 12
```

Comment: This won't work with pseudo-dates stored as strings.

Comment: Oh thanks - i had not seen that. But there is still a good answer from Gordon

Answer (score 1):

Your "dates" are stored as strings, presumably with the month first.  So, the following `order by` should work

```
order by right(date, 4), left(date, 2)
```

You need to put the year before the month for ordering purposes.

If you want the last twelve months, I would recommend:

```
where right(date, 4) * 12 + left(date, 2) >= year(now()) * 12 + month(now())
order by right(date, 4), left(date, 2)
```

The `where` statement converts the dates to a number of months, for both the "date" column in your data and for the current time.

Comment: why dont you simply add `DESC LIMIT 12` to your first query instead of adding where condition ?

Comment: @krishna . . . How do I know that each of the preceding 12 months actually has data?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
SELECT * FROM shop_stats where date >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ORDER BY date
```

Edit:
How about converting the string to date & doing the appropriate date operations in the sql ?

```
SELECT DATE
    ,t1.value
FROM (
    SELECT DATE
        ,STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT (
                '01/'
                ,DATE
                ), '%d/%m/%Y') date_
        ,value
    FROM shop_stats
    ) t1
WHERE t1.date_ >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
ORDER BY t1.date_ DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be05/8

Comment: This won't work with pseudo-dates stored as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your field date has a type string

So you try this:

```
SELECT * FROM shop_stats 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(date, 4, 4) desc,
substring(date, 1, 2) DESC LIMIT 12
```

Show [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0436e/7/0)

Answer (score 0):

select * from shop_stats where date >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ORDER BY date